# How can I map a memory of bytes from a kernel module to user space app?

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, kernel

I would like to declare an array in kernel module and to access it within a userspace app. how can I do it?

How do I memory map it for using via userspace so it can be used by a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most likely need to implement a character device. Then in your instance of `struct file_operations` implement the [mmap function](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s8).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have everything here: http://www.scs.ch/~frey/linux/memorymap.html

First result on Google, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[Linux Device Driver 3th](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) Chapter 15. It talks about mmap. Chapter 3 and 6 talk about char devices.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the userspace I/O system will help you: https://www.osadl.org/?id=321